# missing Non-Color option for color space in Image Texture Node

Tags: texturing, image, color

I am attending a course for Blender that covers version 2.80. I have 2.93.3 (running on Xubuntu 21.10).

When I place an image texture node I would expect to find "non-Color", "Raw", etc. in the "Color Space" dropdown, as described [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/image/image_settings.html#editors-image-image-settings-common).

instead I only found these two entries:
[image]

Where have these settings been moved to in newer versions? Or is it just me doing something wrong?

Comment: Starting in 2.9 the available options in that field depend on what, if anything, is in the image field, but for a jpg file, you should be seeing a non color as an option. does "Rove...jpg" actually exist?

Comment: also, there were some bugs in 2.93.3, related to image textures, so maybe upgrade to 2.93.6.

Comment: ...or 2.93.7 which is the latest LTS version.

Comment: @MartyFouts Yes the file exists, and upgrading to 2.93.7 problem is solved